# createTimeSlices function in CARET package in R

Tags: r, time-series, r-caret

I am working with multivariate financial time series data and having problems using the `createTimeSlices` function. I cannot find any use of the function except the one used by [Max Kuhn](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/splitting.html). Can anybody help me in understanding the usage of the function?

Answer (score 15):

The documentation is being "improved" on this feature (in other words, it currently sucks). Another person contacted me recently about this and here is the example:

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
data(economics)
myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                              initialWindow = 36,
                              horizon = 12,
                              fixedWindow = TRUE)

plsFitTime <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert,
                    data = economics,
                    method = "pls",
                    preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                    trControl = myTimeControl)
```

Max

Comment: is timeslice doing time-series cross-validation?

Comment: Same here...is timeslice doing time-series cross-validation or do I have to partition via `createTimeSlices`first an then  cross-validation? Thankx

Comment: Check out the diagram at the bottom of [this page](http://topepo.github.io/caret/splitting.html) for a good illustration on `createTimeSlices`

Comment: @n1k31t4: that page was renamed to [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#data-splitting-for-time-series)

Comment: The `createTimeSlices` doc has moved to [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#data-splitting-for-time-series)